# Using my matlab GUI script on other PC

Tags: matlab

I developed a simple matlab app, it is an image viewer. The app catch keyboard event to switch image. On my pc it is all ok.

I pass the script files to a friend and when he press keyboard buttons has this error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'image_viewer' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> @(hObject, eventdata)image_viewer('figure1_WindowKeyPressFcn,hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)

??? Error using ==> waitfor
Error while avaluating figure WindowKeyPressFcn
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you copy `image_viewer.m` file to your friend?

Comment: yes i copied image_viewer.m and image_viewer.fig, there are only two files of the project :) image_viewer.m contains function figure1_WindowKeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to answer thoroughly with little details.

I guess it could be a problem of path settings.
Maybe you have the path set correctly on your pc, but your friend has not.

To add a folder to path you can use the function `addpath('your_dir/')`.
If you need to add to the path a directory with all the subfolders you can try `addpath(genpath('your_dir/')`.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the answer, the strange thing is that my project is only one .m file and one .fig file so if there are path problems the program should not be open on my friend pc...